# How can you check the value of a property in application.properties for a springboot application after the application is running?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, properties, application.properties

Let's say I set up a Spring boot application as a jar which has a property as part of the `application.properties`:

```
test.name=John
```

Now SpringBoot provides a way for running this jar and updating that value in the command so something like:

```sh
java -jar app.jar --test.name=Jimmy
```

Now say the application has been running for a while and I want to find out what the value of this property is whilst application is running.

How can I find this out because looking at the application.properties in the jar file it would still say `John` but this was overridden when I ran the application using the `java -jar` command?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create configuration class and get target param, look below.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

   @Value("${myExampleParam}")
   private String myExampleParam;

   public String getMyExampleParam() {
      return myExampleParam;
   }

}
```